# Minimize the impact on memory on generating and downloading a file

Tags: spring-boot

For testing purposes only, I created this controller, which generates a 100MB file and returns it to the client. The method is very fast. The content of the file does not matter. The file is generated on the fly, it is not saved to disk.

Is it possible to reduce the impact on memory, particularly on java heap? Thank you

```
    @GetMapping("/testDownload100MB")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download100MB() throws IOException {

        int sizeInBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(sizeInBytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeInBytes; i++) {
            outStream.write(0);
        }
        Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(outStream.toByteArray());

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(utilities.getGenericHttpHeadersToDownloadFile())
                .contentLength(sizeInBytes)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(resource);
    }
```

The code of `utilities.getGenericHttpHeadersToDownloadFile()` is not relevant for the question, however I report it for completeness:

```
    public HttpHeaders getGenericHttpHeadersToDownloadFile() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=myfile");
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");
        return headers;
    }
```

Comment: Use `StreamingResponseBody`?

Comment: I looked at the javadoc, but I don't know how to use StreamingResponseBody. Could you elaborate on your answer, with a complete code that can replace mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The code in my question throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` on my Spring Boot server. This new code solves the issue:

```
    @GetMapping("/testDownload100MB")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download100MB() throws IOException {

        int size1MB = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // size in bytes

        File tempFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "tempFile" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size1MB);
            for (int j = 0; j < size1MB; j++) {
                outStream.write(0);
            }
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(tempFile, outStream.toByteArray(), true); // append to the temp file
        }

        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(tempFile);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // we can assume that the file can be safely deleted after five minutes
               tempFile.delete();
            }
        }, 1000 * 60 * 5);


        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(utilities.getGenericHttpHeadersToDownloadFile())
                .contentLength(tempFile.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(resource);
    }
```

Note that `FileUtils` must be imported with: `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`.

In this case, no objects exceeding 1 MB are placed in the java heap. In addition, `FileSystemResource` does not need to load the entire file into memory. On the other hand, I had to add a timer to delete the file: since this is a method for testing purposes, I can safely assume that after a few minutes the file is no longer needed.

If there are better solutions that do not require a temporary file, add your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

using StreamingResponseBody you do not need to store memory or file. it send to client directly.

here is the example:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class StreamingController {

    @GetMapping("/download")
    public StreamingResponseBody download() {
        return outputStream -> {
            int sizeInBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
            // Generate and write bytes to the output stream
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeInBytes; i++) {
                outputStream.write(0);
                if(i%(1024 * 1024)==0)
                outputStream.flush(); // flush bytes to client every 1Mb

            }
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.close();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: After three years, I no longer remember which project the code you replied to referred to. Anyway, you actually answered my question to suggest a solution without using a temporary file. I have no way to test it, so I give you a +1 for trust and to thank you. Your answer will be useful for other people or even myself in the future.